# I have a problem with firebase after post a data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm working with RTK query in my react project as a fetching/caching module which is great but after POST a data to my firebase database something like a random id which made up by firebase subcategorizes all my data and disrupts the structure of my data
I put a picture which shows how data getting store on the firebase :
[image]

and below code is the RTK query handler

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import {
  AllBurgerType,
  BurgerType,
} from "../*********************";

export const burgerApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "burgerApi",
  tagTypes: ["Ingredients"],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl:
      "https://************************.firebasedatabase.app",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
  // I've rid other methods
    addIngredients: builder.mutation({
      query: (initialIngredients) => ({
        url: "/.json",
        method: "POST",
        body: initialIngredients,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Ingredients"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetIngredientsQuery,
  useAddIngredientsMutation,
  useEditIngredientsMutation,
} = burgerApi;
```

and add new data like on the other file like this :

```
import { useAddIngredientsMutation } from "../../../../Api/apiSlice";

  const [addNewIng, { isLoading, isSuccess }] = 
  useAddIngredientsMutation();
  await addNewIng(store.getState().burger).unwrap();
```

how should I prevent this

Comment: `POST /.json` will perform a Database push. You'll need to swap to using `PATCH /.json` and tweak your request body as appropriate. Sorry I'm unavailable to smash out a more detailed answer but that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: that's it, works for me